# Accessing Watch Faces with the XCUITest Framework

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, xcuitest, apple-watch-complication

## Context

I'm building Unit Tests for the Apple Watch using the XCUITest library. I'd like to take screenshots of the Watch Faces on the simulator, so I was thinking on using the bundle ID of the 'Clock App' via the:

`XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.bundle.applicationName")`

But I can't seem to be able to control the watch faces on my UI Test.

## Specific Question

- Is there a way to get Apple's Watch Application's Bundle IDs?
- Alternatively, is there a better way of trying to control the Watch Faces?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to do this either as of Xcode 14 beta. See this post I made - I'm guessing we just can't get to the watch faces for ui testing just yet https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708196